# Open specific album of gallery form android app

Tags: android, android-gallery

Is it possible to open specific album of gallery from application?
I have searched on internet, but did not find anything like this. I found that how to get reference of images from specific album and display them inside the app at my own. Need to know about the above mentioned possibility of opening gallery from app (but specific album of gallery not just gallery)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to locate the URI of that specific album's name saved on the SDcard. Something like this could help you

```
intent.setType("file:///sdcard/image/nameofyouralbum/*");
```

OR `intent.setType("file:///sdcard/nameofyouralbum/*");`